# Nuxt/content - How to display a list of articles on the article page (_slug)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using the nuxt/content module to create a documentation site.

On the [Nuxt blog](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content) they have one post displaying the content on a separated index.vue page and the post details on the _slug.vue page.

What I'm trying to do is show the list of articles/posts on the same page using a different layout.

Here is the folder structure I'm using:

```
content (folder)
    articles (folder)
        article1.md
        article2.md
        article3.md
pages (folder)
    blog (folder)
        _slug.vue
        index.vue
```

And that's my_slug.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <aside class="w-1/3">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="article in articles" :key="article.slug">
          <NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'blog-slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
            <div>
              <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
            </div>
          </NuxtLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <main class="w-full">
      <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>

      <p>Article last updated: {{ formatDate(article.updatedAt) }}</p>

      <nuxt-content :document="article" />

      <prev-next :prev="prev" :next="next" />
    </main>
    <aside class="w-1/3">
      <h4>On this page</h4>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="link of article.toc" :key="link.id">
            <NuxtLink :to="`#${link.id}`" :class="{ 'py-2': link.depth === 2, 'ml-2 pb-2': link.depth === 3 }">{{ link.text }}</NuxtLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

      async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
        const articles = await $content('articles', params.slug)
          .only(['title', 'slug'])
          .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
          .fetch()

        const article = await $content('articles', params.slug).fetch()

        const [prev, next] = await $content('articles')
          .only(['title', 'slug'])
          .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
          .surround(params.slug)
          .fetch()

        return {
          articles,
          article,
          prev,
          next
        }
      },
    methods: {
      formatDate(date) {
        const options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' }
        return new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en', options)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If I use the "Display all articles" piece of code on the index.vue page it works but together on the _slug.vue the list is now empty.

Here is the index where the posts are showing up correctly:

```
<template>
   <div>
    <h1>Blog Posts</h1>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="article of articles" :key="article.slug">
        <NuxtLink :to="{ name: 'blog-slug', params: { slug: article.slug } }">
          <div>
            <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>
          </div>
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
      const articles = await $content('articles', params.slug)
        .only(['title', 'slug'])
        .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
        .fetch()

      return {
        articles
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Am I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No articles are retrieved because your query isn't correct, you must search in the `articles` folder:

```js
const articles = await $content('articles') // instead of $content('articles', params.slug)
  .only(['title', 'slug'])
  .sortBy('createdAt', 'asc')
  .fetch()
```